# How to respond to HyperV Stop-VM prompts in PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am writing a script to carry out maintenance on several virtual machines running on Hyper-V

As part of this, I need to stop the VMs but if there is any kind of problem with stopping them, I want to abort the process

Problem is, Stop-VM prompts for confirmation if it encounters any problems and there doesn't seem to be any way to automate a response (there are no switches to the cmdlet to control what happens in these cases, -confirm:$false doesn't work, -force is the opposite of what I want, and sending STDIN to the cmdlet gives an error as it expects to receive a virtual machine via the pipeline

As an example, if the integration services are unavailable you get prompted to force a shutdown, which I would want to answer No to:

```
> stop-vm testvm01

    Confirm

    Hyper-V can't shut down virtual machine "testvm01" because the Shutdown integration service is unavailable. You can turn off the virtual machine by selecting [Y]es, but this is similar to pulling the power on a physical machine. To avoid potential data loss, select

    [N]o, then pause or save the virtual machine. Do you want to turn off the virtual machine?

    [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

How can I script a response to this prompt?

Comment: This sounds ridiculous - as in: this is a query and -confirm and -force should do exactly that and not ask for further input. Are you using a current version? This sounds like a bug - and a critical that is, because it seriously makes large parts of vm scripting unusable.

Comment: @TomTom They kind of do the opposite. -force will force the VM to shutdown regardless of any issues (and without prompting) while -confirm:$false simply tells the cmdlet that it shouldn't prompt for confirmation before running a high impact command and again that would result in the command running whereas I want to abort it

Comment: If you know the conditions you want to avoid, can you query the machines for those cases and avoid trying to stop them?  Or always explicitly save them?  I don't have a test machine handy, but you could also try `Stop-VM -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Stop` to see how that interacts with the confirmation prompts.